# How to filter a list of dicts comparing it with a json file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have an output that is a list of dicts:

output:

```
[{'name' : 'andres', 'age': 10},
 {'name' : 'paul', 'age' :20}]
```

Now I want to filter this out to get the name of who is older than a THRESOLH.This threshold comes from a json file that has this structure:

```
{"NAMES":['andres', 'paul'], "THRESHOLD":{'andres':14, 'paul': 16}}
```

The expected output is: `['paul']` because **`paul's age in output is 20 and the threshold for him is 16**, so **20 > 16** ok!

**What I am doing:**

```
THRESHOLD_ = json_file_name['THESHOLD]
NAMES_ = json_file_name['NAMES']
```

and then:

```
final_output = [dict(name=i, bio_age for i,w in output if i['age'] >= THRESHOLD_.get(i)]
```

This is not working:

I want as final output:

1 - dictionary {'name':age'} of people with age higher than it's age limit in json_file

2 - list of name of people with age higher than it's age limit in json_file

```
{"paul":20}, ['paul']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a dictionary comprehension - https://akuiper.com/console/iVq4s2J3kwdR

```
lst = [{'name' : 'andres', 'age': 10},
 {'name' : 'paul', 'age' :20}]
thresh = {"NAMES":['andres', 'paul'], "THRESHOLD":{'andres':14, 'paul': 16}}

{d['name']: d['age'] for d in lst if d['age'] > thresh['THRESHOLD'].get(d['name'], 0)}
# {'paul': 20}
```

To get the keys:

```
filtered = {d['name']: d['age'] for d in lst if d['age'] > thresh['THRESHOLD'].get(d['name'], 0)}
list(filtered.keys())
# ['paul']
```